# I have to solve the complex equation $2\operatorname{Im}(z)+1=\operatorname{Re}(z^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$2\operatorname{Im}(z)+1=\operatorname{Re}(z^2)$ all complex solutions of the equation. So I started basically with stating $z=a+bi$ Therefore $\operatorname{Im}(z)=b$, $z^2=(a^2-b^2)+(2abi)$, and therefore $\operatorname{Re}(z^2)=a^2-b^2$. So I have that $2b+1=a^2-b^2 $ but I don't know what to do next. All solutions should be given in form of $z=a+bi$ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there! Note that\begin{align}2b+1=a^2-b^2&\iff b^2+2b+1=a^2\\&\iff(b+1)^2=a^2\\&\iff b+1=\pm a.\end{align}So, the solutions are the numbers of the form $a+(a-1)i$ ($a\in\Bbb R$), together with those of the form $a-(a+1)i$ (again, with $a\in\Bbb R$).

Comment: Could you please tell me how you are reaching to the solutions in a more extended form, thanks.

Comment: I guess  i have it. $b= a-1$ or $b=-a -1$

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.

Comment: as always in mathematics once you write all the things down, it becomes way easier :D Thanks Jose